# Matlab simple loop for different function variables

Tags: matlab

I wrote a simple MatLab script to evaluate `forward`, `backward` and `central` difference approximations of first and second derivatives for a spesific function

`(y = x^3-5x)`

at two different `x` values

```
(x=0.5 and x = 1.5)
```

and  for 7 different step sizes `h` and compare the relative errors of the approximations to the analytical derivatives.

However, i need to enter `x` and `h` values manually every time. Question is, how do I create a loop for 7 different `h` values and 2 different `x` values and get all the results as a matrix?

```
clc
clear all
close all

h = 0.00001;
x1 = 0.5;

y = @(x) x.^3 - 5*x;
dy = @(x) 3*x.^2 - 5;
ddy = @(x) 6*x;
d1 = dy(x1);
d2 = ddy(x1);

%Forward Differencing

f1 = (y(x1+h) - y(x1))/h;
f2 = (y(x1+2*h) - 2*y(x1+h) + y(x1))/(h.^2);

%Central Differencing

c1 = (y(x1+h)-y(x1-h))/(2*h);
c2 = (y(x1+h)-2*y(x1)+y(x1-h))/(h.^2);

% Backward Differencing

b1 = (y(x1) - y(x1-h))/h;
b2 = (y(x1)-2*y(x1-h)+y(x1-2*h))/(h.^2);

% Relative Errors

ForwardError1 = (f1 - dy(x1))/dy(x1);
ForwardError2 = (f2 - ddy(x1))/ddy(x1);

CentralError1 = (c1 - dy(x1))/dy(x1);
CentralError2 = (c2 - ddy(x1))/ddy(x1);

BackwardError1 = (b1 - dy(x1))/dy(x1);
BackwardError2 = (b2 - ddy(x1))/ddy(x1);
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a loop. You can use [`meshgrid`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/meshgrid.html) to create all combinations of your arguments (`x` and `h` in your case) and use these as inputs to your functions.

To get combinations of `x = [0.5, 1.5]` and `h=0.00001:0.00001:0.00007` (I assume since you did not specify `h` values in the question), you would do:

```
[x, h] = meshgrid([0.5, 1.5], 0.00001:0.00001:0.00007);
y = @(x) x.^3 - 5*x;
f1 = (y(x1+h) - y(x1))./h;
```

Here `x,h` are matrices of size 7x2, and so is the result `f1`. Note that `/` was changed to `./` as `h` is a matrix and we want per-element operations.

Comment: Alternatively/in addition to this you might want to write your script as a function which takes an input of `x` and `h`. You could get it returning the 6 outputs with the function definition like `function [ForwardError1, ForwardError2, CentralError1, CentralError2, BackwardError1, BackwardError2] = calc_my_errors(x,h)` (then remove the clear all). See [function](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/function.html).